# How to assure the selection of an open port in shell

Tags: bash, shell, port

So I have a script that creates a tunnel. To do that it uses random ports.
This is the logic for random port generation

```
RPORT=1
while [ $RPORT -lt 2000 ]
        do
        RPORT=$[($RANDOM % 3000) + 1]
done
```

This is good only if the port that it selects isn't in use. If that port is active, I am unable to access that server while that port is being used.

I want to do something like this

```
while [netsat -nat | grep $RPORT] = true
       do
       RPORT=$[($RANDOM % 3000) + 1]
```

So I want to check first if that port is in use, if so, search for another random port, check if it is in use, if no then use it.

Thank you very much in advance for you time and help!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/885414/linux-command-get-unused-port

Comment: Thank a lot for the link! This function was what I needed.                                 `code`function random_unused_port {
   (netstat --listening --all --tcp --numeric | 
    sed '1,2d; s/[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*:\([0-9]*\)[[:space:]]*.*/\1/g' |
    sort -n | uniq; seq 1 1000; seq 1 65535
    ) | sort -n | uniq -u | shuf -n 1
}

RANDOM_PORT=$(random_unused_port)`code`

Answer (score 0):

```
function random_unused_port {
   (netstat --listening --all --tcp --numeric | 
    sed '1,2d; s/[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*:\([0-9]*\)[[:space:]]*.*/\1/g' |
    sort -n | uniq; seq 1 1000; seq 1 65535
    ) | sort -n | uniq -u | shuf -n 1
}

RANDOM_PORT=$(random_unused_port)
```

This was the function that helped me out!
Thank you Nahuel Fouilleul for the link!

Comment: Note: I didn't mention this answer and I don't think it does expected because `seq 1 65535` will generate all ports then `sort -n | uniq -u` (or shorter `sort -nu`) will merge with other list (??)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the answer, also because port from 1 to 1000 are reserved seq starts at 1001

```
grep -F -x -v -f <(
    netstat --listening --all --tcp --numeric |
    sed '1,2d; s/[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*:\([0-9]*\)[[:space:]]*.*/\1/g' |
    sort -nu
) <(seq 1001 65536) | shuf -n 1
```

Comment: Thank you Nahuel! That's what I did with the port range, I did set it actually from 20000 to 65536 so it won't use the reserved ports. What would be the difference of inserting the grep command?`grep -F -x -v -f`. Thanks!

Comment: grep -v is doing second set minus first set whereas in other answer it's a union and can return any port between 1 and 65536